# Unit testing ngComponentRouter - Angular 1.5.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-1.6, ngcomponentrouter

I am trying to build basic unit tests for an Angular 1.5 with the purpose of A) practicing unit testing, and B) familiarizing myself with component-based development in Angular 1.5.x. I'm trying to unit test a simple component, but I keep getting the following message:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
>
> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   ngComponentRouter due to:
>
> Error: [$injector:nomod] Module
>   'ngComponentRouter' is not available! You either misspelled the module
>   name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you
>   specify the dependencies as the second argument.

I'd like a little guidance on how to inject this specific dependency/module into a unit test. This is the code I have:

**app.js**

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    const app = angular.module("app", ["ngComponentRouter"])

    app.value("$routerRootComponent", "componentApp");
})();
```

**component-app.component.js**

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    angular.module("app").component("componentApp", {
        templateUrl: "/javascripts/component-app.component.html",
        controller: ["$router", function($router){
            $router.config([
                { path: "/users", component: "usersComponent", name: "Users" },
                { path: "/**", redirectTo: ["Users"]}
            ]);
        }]

    });
})();
```

**component-app.component.spec.js**

```
describe("componentApp component", function(){
    beforeEach(module("app"));

    var $componentController, componentApp;

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector){
        $componentController = $injector.get("$componentController");
        componentApp = $componentController("componentApp", { $scope: {}});
    }));

    it("componentApp component is defined", function(){
        expect(componentApp).toBeDefined();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: You don't have component router loaded in tests. You shouldn't use the real router in *unit* tests, because unit tests are for testing a specific unit (your own code) in isolation. Mock $router service. Btw, component router is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So two changes did the trick, first I need to change component-app.component.js:

```
angular.module("app").component("componentApp", {
    templateUrl: "/templates/component-app.component.html",
    $routeConfig: [
        { path: "/Users", name: "Users", component: "usersComponent" },
        { path: "/Home", name: "Home", component: "homeComponent"},
        { path: "/Profile/:id", name: "Profile", component: "profileComponent" },
        { path: "/**", redirectTo: ["Users"]}
    ]
});
```

And I needed to include the file in karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: "",
    frameworks: ["jasmine"],
    files: [
        "bower_components/angular/angular.js",       
        "bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js",
        "bower_components/angular-component-router/angular_1_router.js",
        "javascripts/**/*.js"
    ],
    exclude: [        
    ],
    preprocessors: {
    },
    reporters: ["progress"],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ["Chrome"],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  });
};
```